# aligning <div> data in one line?

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="surveyTitleEdit" style="float:left;overflow: auto;">
   <input id="surveyTitleInput"  size="25" type="text" name="Title" />
   <span><img class="pointerCursor" src="image" alt="Save" title="Save"
              onclick="save()"/></span>
   <span><img class="pointerCursor" src="image" alt="Save" title="Save"
              onclick=Edit();"/></span>
</div>
```

This is my code, I'm getting input box and first image in one line and the second image in another line , I want all the div data in one line , how can i achieve this?

Comment: I don't know where your code is.  You should post it here of course.

Comment: `<imgtag>` is not a valid HTML tag. What doesn't work, what's the problem?

Comment: no since i cant  post img i specified imgtag,  i want all these <div> data into one line

Comment: There's only one DIV in your example. I suggest you post a live example up on jsfiddle.net

Comment: what is the div or the container of this div? probably because the parent div width is set to some value, and that cause its content to be moved to newline caused by not enough width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div id="surveyTitleEdit">
 <input id="surveyTitleInput" size="25" type="text" name="Title"/>
 <img src="" alt=""/>
 <img src="" alt=""/>
</div>
```

Now the only thing you have to make sure of, is that the div `surveyTitleEdit` is wide enough (has a width higher than the sum of the widths of the input and two images) to contain the 3 elements next to each other. Alternatively you can use the following CSS:

```
#surveyTitleEdit {
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `onclick="Edit();"`. You forgot a `"`. Elements should be automatically aligned if the div container is wider enough. Whenever possible, avoid to attach events directly to TAGS. Instead, you can use jQuery (Or other frameworks) events.

Comment: that is not a good advice. jquery provides elements functions from JS closures. Some browsers leak memory because of that.

Comment: Intresting, didn't know that. Can you provide me some related article please? I wish to investigate. Thank you.

Comment: As long as you expect page refreshes - the leak is mostly solved when the page refreshes.
But when you're strateging for 1-page-app - you're in trouble. There's many articles if you google 'javascript memory leak' Here's a good start that points also a solution.
http://javascript.crockford.com/memory/leak.html. P.S - crockford is actually the father of JS, go to the root of this linked site and have lott'a fun :)

Answer (score -1):

Try specifying the height and width in the , as in:

```
<img src="image.jpg" width="200" height="150">
```